# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9 in tid 31051

Tags: android, linux, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I building project ,I able login my account and it is unable to living stream .
Camera is ok. When the program is execution to Ffmpeg_init() that will be error.
I get a few of question,

Question1.
E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
I don't know this error what happened.

Question2.
I use addr2line (NDK-TOOLTAIONS) to debug , I get some message.
pc 0050c99c /data/app/com.cmore.youtube-2/lib/arm/libffmpeg.so (avcodec_get_context_defaults3+56)
I didn't never modify this file.

```
10-15 18:39:17.848 31051-31051/com.cmore.youtube A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9 in tid 31051 (m.cmore.youtube)
10-15 18:39:17.898 430-430/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-15 18:39:17.898 430-430/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'htc/htc_asia_tw/htc_a51dtul:6.0.1/MMB29M/738098.3:user/release-keys'
10-15 18:39:17.898 430-430/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
10-15 18:39:17.898 430-430/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
10-15 18:39:17.898 430-430/? A/DEBUG: pid: 31051, tid: 31051, name: m.cmore.youtube >>> com.cmore.youtube <<<
10-15 18:39:17.898 430-430/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x9
10-15 18:39:17.898 433-31603/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
10-15 18:39:17.898 433-31603/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
10-15 18:39:17.908 430-430/? A/DEBUG: r0 ab36b9a0 r1 00000000 r2 00000000 r3 d6a225c0
10-15 18:39:17.908 430-430/? A/DEBUG: r4 d6a35d18 r5 00000001 r6 ab36b6f0 r7 ab36aac0
10-15 18:39:17.908 430-430/? A/DEBUG: r8 ab36b9a0 r9 00000001 sl 12c590f0 fp 000001e0
10-15 18:39:17.908 430-430/? A/DEBUG: ip 00000000 sp ffcb4778 lr d6440980 pc d644099c cpsr 200f0010
10-15 18:39:17.918 430-430/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
10-15 18:39:17.918 430-430/? A/DEBUG: #00 pc 0050c99c /data/app/com.cmore.youtube-2/lib/arm/libffmpeg.so (avcodec_get_context_defaults3+56)
```

Answer (score 0):

My Cocos2d project also found this error, the reason is that one Json file exported by CocosStudio , has a imageview that its path was reseted to the initial value (a PC path), so my PC can find this path but the android can not, so it has this error. You can just find this json file and reexport it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is somewhere with this lib: libffmpeg.so

Check if you use some unusual video encoders, formats, bitrates, aspect ratios or something like that.